# I clicked a IP logger link

Tags: privacy

I clicked an IP logger link. I am worried someone might send CP with my IP address and I would get wrongfully arrested. Will this happen? Or am I relatively safe?

Answer (score 2):

This will not happen. You are safe.

Your IP address is public knowledge (but identifying). Every-time you load some content on the web (a web page, an image, a video...), you give the server hosting the content your IP address so it can send this content back to your computer.

You do not have to click on a link to give someone your IP address. Knowing your IP address is not enough to be able to usurp it.

---

Most likely, your IP address is the one of your home router (typically when using IPv4). It could also directly be the address of your computer (only when using IPv6).

To usurp the IP address of your home router, an attacker must have under its control some running software on one of your computers (your smartphone using the router's WiFi counts too).

To usurp the IP address of your computer, the attacker must either:

- have under its control some running software on your computer,
- or it must have an access to your local (home) network. For example by being a neighbor with your WiFi passphrase. With this access it could run an "ARP spoofing" attack to usurp your computer's IP address.